# Which esper level is Shirai Kuroko, the girl who can teleport?

Tags: a-certain-magical-index, a-certain-scientific-railgun

Shirai Kuroto is a esper who appears (at least) in A certain Magical Index and A certain Scientific Raigun being a somehow important character. Which esper level is she supposed to be? Is this ever revealed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [wikia](https://toarumajutsunoindex.fandom.com/wiki/Shirai_Kuroko) Kuroko is a Level 4

> Shirai Kuroko (白井 黒子 Shirai Kuroko?) is a Level 4 esper and a student of Tokiwadai Middle School, as well as a member of Judgment.

[image: Kuroko's Level]

She is also listed on the [Wikia's Category for Level 4 Espers](https://toarumajutsunoindex.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Level_4_Espers)